# How many time I need to pick random number [1,N] to get specific number k

Tags: probability

I'm working on proving something regarding probability and statistics.

How many time I need to pick a random number from [1,N] to get specific number k, where k in [1,N]

```
start = random(1,N);
count = 1;
do
{
   end = random(1,N);
   count++;
}while (start!=end);
```

My experiments concluded that if I repeat above program for 100 time for the same N value then average value of count ~ N. I don't know how to prove that theoretically.

Any one can help me to prove it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you pick a random number between `1` and `N`, you have a **probability** of getting `k` which is equal to `1/N`, and a probability of getting something different which is equal to `(N-1)/N`.

Once you know this, you can compute the probability of getting `k` in :

- 1 shot : `P1 = 1/N`
- 2 shots : `P2 = (N-1)/N * 1/N`
- 3 shots : `P3 = (N-1/N * (N-1)/N * 1/N`
- ...

The expected number of times you have to pick a random number in order to get `k` is:

```
1 * P1 + 2 * P2 + 3 * P3 + 4 * P4...
```

This is a series that converges to the value `N`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I got the answer. If X is the expected number of trials required to randomly generate k until k= target value then,

X = (1/N)*1  + ((N-1)/N)*(X+1)

Solving this equation gives X=N.